# Why does $\cos(x)$ differentiate to $-\sin(x)$ (limits specific)?

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives, trigonometry

I have just attempted to differentiate $\cos(x)$ from first principles, and it feels like taking the limit as $h$ aproaches $0$ is inconsistent.

Here's how I did it:

If $f(x) = \cos(x)$, then $f'(x)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\cos(x+h)-\cos(x)}{h}$

So $f'(x)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\cos(x)\cos(h)-\sin(x)\sin(h)-\cos(x)}{h}$

Then, as ${h\to 0}$, we can use small angle approximations for $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$, so:

$f'(x)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\cos(x)(1-\frac{h^2}{2})-\sin(x)(h)-\cos(x)}{h}$

Also, if ${h\to 0}$, then ${(1-\frac{h^2}{2})\to 1}$

So $f'(x)=\frac{\cos(x)(1)-\sin(x)(h)-\cos(x)}{h}$

So $f'(x)=\frac{\cos(x)-\sin(x)(h)-\cos(x)}{h}$

So $f'(x)=\frac{-\sin(x)(h)}{h}$

So $f'(x)=-\sin(x)$

I got to the derivative, but my question is:

Why, when considering the limit as ${h\to 0}$, did we not say that ${\sin(x)(h)\to 0}$?

Wouldn't $\sin(x)$ multiplied by something tiny approximately equal 0?

The same way that something tiny squared divided by 2 approximately equals 0?

Am unsure about when we can treat $h$ as $0$ when taking the limit.

Comment: The same question would be why does $\lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{5h}{h}=5$, since shouldn't the numerator go to 0?  If you want to consider $\frac{\sin(h)}{h}$ for small $h$, try computing for $h=0.001$. https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sin%28.001%29%2F.001

Comment: It is very strange in your steps that $\lim_{h\to 0}$ has disappeared, but the $h$ remains

Comment: @311411 Doesn't seem strange at all to me. I make that same mistake all the time.

Comment: @311411 Writing the limit notation in LaTeX is quite a pain. I've omitted it in intermediate steps too.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, $\sin(x)$ times something tiny is tiny. But $\sin(x)$ times something tiny *and then divided by something tiny* doesn't have to be tiny anymore. Besides, note that, if your argument was correct, we would have $\lim_{x\to0}\frac xx=0$, since the numerator is tiny. But, of course, that limit is $1$.

Answer (score 2):

From this step:

$f'(x)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\cos(x)\cos(h)-\sin(x)\sin(h)-\cos(x)}{h}$, factor out $\cos(x)$ and $\sin(x)$ and write it as two limits. In other words,
\begin{align}
f'(x)&=\cos(x)\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\cos(h)-1}{h}-\sin(x)\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\sin(h)}{h}.
\end{align}
Then the problem is simply a matter of showing that the first limit is $0$ and the second limit is $1$. There are many resources explaining these limits.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are pointing out the "Ghosts of Departed Quantities" Berkeley mentioned in [The Analyst](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Analyst):
"And what are these Fluxions? The Velocities of evanescent Increments? And what are these same evanescent Increments? They are neither finite Quantities nor Quantities infinitely small, nor yet nothing. May we not call them the ghosts of departed quantities?"

Note in the definition of the derivative it looks like there is a division by zero at the start. In the early stages of taking the limit, $h$ is treated as if it's not zero, the expression is simplified with algebra, then at the final stage, it's set equal to zero.

In early calculus courses, teachers often skip over the rigorous definition of limits and the derivative, so that behavior of multiplying by zero yet not getting zero remains unexplained.

More rigorous proof:

$0\le x<\pi/2\implies 0 \le \sin{x}\le x$ and $0<1-\cos{x}<x$:

Consider a unit circle in the x-y plane centered at the origin and an inscribed right triangle with its base lying on the +x-axis. Extend the base to the right to intersect the circle and call this part of the x axis not part of the triangle B. Let the radian measure of the angle with vertex at the origin be $x$. Draw Line Segment A from the vertex of the right triangle not on the x axis to the point where the extended base intersects the circle. The length of the arc cut off by line A is $x$. Line Segment A is the shortest distance between the endpoints of that arc, so the arc is longer. Further, Segment A is the hypotenuse of the right triangle consisting of the vertical leg of the original right triangle and B. So the hypotenuse is longer than the vertical leg. But the vertical leg has length $\sin{x}$, so $\sin{x}<$hypotenuse$<$arc$=x$. B has length $1-\cos{x}$ and so is less than $x$ by similar arguments. QED

You probably want to avoid the small angle approximation here unless you can prove it without using Taylor Series approximation which relies on derivatives making the reasoning circular.

By the second triangle above, $\sin^2{x}+(1-\cos{x})^2=2(1-\cos{x})<x^2\implies 0<\frac{1-\cos{x}}{x}<x/2$

We have a third triangle if we consider the radius of the unit circle on the x axis,  and construct a vertical leg to meet the indefinitely extended hypotenuse of the first triangle.

The area of this third triangle is $.5*\tan{x}$ and it includes the area of the subtended sector which has area $x/2$. It follows that $x<\tan{x}$.

Given $0<\sin{x}<x<\tan{x}=\sin{x}/\cos{x}$, it follows that $1<x/\sin{x}<1/\cos{x}$ and by taking reciprocals, $\cos{x}<\sin{x}/x<1$.

By [The Squeeze Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem) it then follows that $\lim_{x\to0} \sin{x}/x=1$

So applying this to the definition of the derivative:

$\frac{\cos{x}\cos{h}-\sin{x}\sin{h}-\cos{x}}{h}=-\sin{x}\frac{\sin{h}}{h}-\frac{1-\cos{h}}{h}\cos{x}$

the term on the right goes to zero and the term on the left approaches $-\sin{x}$

This gives the expected result using elementary inequalities and avoids the disappearing variables.

Comment: You can use \le to produce $\le$.